# Measuring Correlation of 2 Dichotomous DVs in a Repeated Measures Design

Tags: correlation, mixed-model, repeated-measures, binary-data

I have 8 subjects. They were all tested under 2 different conditions, 5 sessions of each, with 14 trials in a session. Total data points: 1120. No data is missing. 2 dichotomous DVs were measured every trial (Did they make a response? and Did they do the task correctly?). I want to know if responding predicts correct task performance, or at least if they correlate. Would I need to use mixed-effects modeling?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you want some sort of mixed effect model but questions about SPSS code are off-topic here.

I prefer the term multi-level model; you need one because the data are not independent.

Comment: Apologies for the SPSS question. It's been deleted. But a bit more on the sort of stats I should be using would be helpful. Could I do a multi-level logistic regression, for example?

Comment: Yes, since the DVs are dichotomous, that seems right.